Experiment Update: Hawking Radiation simulations
Sorry for the rapid fire posts, but I want to expand on what my radiation simulation data showed the other day. Though I am getting SU(3) violations even when I treat the bits classically.
If there was one question I would want to ask the community,
How do you model color charge effectively? Why does the green color charge not have the same entropy correlations as the other colors, even when it seems everything is accounted for? Simulating systems with conserved quantities, like color, is essential for building efficient quantum circuits. A failure to conserve color could signal design flaws or suggest areas for algorithm improvement. A real life quantum circuit that is not conserving information directly applies to you. Worse a real quantum system that is exhibiting this behavior might limit future growth in quantum computing.
I encourage looking at my github to see why I am saying the things I am, because this is experimental evidence (or I believe): https://github.com/NiloGregginz33/QMGRExperiments
